# How do I handle CSS with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use just straight vanilla `Node.js` with no frameworks other than what is necessary for educational purposes. I currently have this setup:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  jade = require('jade');

function compile(dirPath, res) {
    var filePath = __dirname + dirPath;
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, fd) {
        var fn = jade.compile(fd, { filename: filePath, pretty: true});
        res.write(fn());
        res.end();
    });

}

exports.compile = compile;
```

Which is called when the requested page is asked for, like this:

```
var jadec = require('./jadecompile');

function start(res, postData) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    var cpage = '/staticpages/index.jade',
         page = jadec.compile(cpage, res);
}
```

The page loads great and I get this as my view source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <link rel="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <p>Hello This Is A Test</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the css doesn't work at all, I've been trying to google it but every answer seems to use express or something else, but I want to learn how to do this as vanilla as possible, so my question is, how can I handle the *.css so that the css is loaded properly, when I click on the `href` link in the view source, it loads my 404 page, rather than just the plain text of the css file. Thanks!

Feel free to view the repo at: https://github.com/Gacnt/Node-Tests

Comment: Have you tried embedding the CSS directly into your index.jade file?

Comment: @Jlange yeah, and it works just fine!

Comment: You'll need to add a static file directory variable somehow to tell your html where these files are located. Try adding a var for this into the call, and then parsing it in the template.

Comment: The problem is in none of the code you posted. Show us how you set up the http module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by creating a function to handle static pages, such as .css or .js, like so:

```
var http = require('http'),
     url = require('url'),
    path = require('path');
      fs = require('fs');

// ADDED THIS FUNCTION HERE -----------------------------------------------------
function handleStaticPages(pathName, res) {
    var ext = path.extname(pathName);
    switch(ext) {
        case '.css':
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/css"});
            fs.readFile('./' + pathName, 'utf8', function(err, fd) {
                res.end(fd);
            });
            console.log('Routed for Cascading Style Sheet '+ pathName +' Successfully\n');
        break;
        case '.js':
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
            fs.readFile('./' + pathName, 'utf8', function(err, fd) {
                res.end(fd);
            });
            console.log('Routed for Javascript '+ pathName +' Successfully\n');
        break;
    }
}
// ADDED THIS FUNCTION HERE -----------------------------------------------------

function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(req, res) {
        var postData = "",
            pathName = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        console.log('Request for ' + pathName + ' received.');

        req.addListener('data', function(data) {
            postData += data;
            console.log('Received POST data chunk ' + postData + '.');
        });

        req.addListener('end', function() {
            var pathext = path.extname(pathName);
            if (pathext === '.js' || pathext === '.css') {
            handleStaticPages(pathName, res);
        } else {
            console.log('--> Routing only the view page');
            route(handle, pathName, res, postData);
        }
        });
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(4000);
    console.log('Server is now listening at: http://127.0.0.1:4000 .');
}

exports.start = start;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle .css and other static files, there needs to be a file stream in place. Rather than using a switch statement you can just use the following.

var stream = fs.createReadStream(path); //create the file stream
stream.pipe(res); //transfer the file